# How to leave all rooms that the socket is connected to at one go in Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have some code where a socket is made to join multiple rooms. At some point in the code, i want to leave all the rooms at one go, without disconnecting the socket. Is it possible to do this? If yes, then how can i do this? Thanks in advance..

I am using socket.IO

Comment: In Socket.IO, you can leave multiple rooms simultaneously without disconnecting the socket by utilizing the `socket.rooms` and `socket.leave` methods. The provided code iterates through each room the socket is currently in and leaves those rooms, excluding the default room (which is the socket's ID): `socket.rooms.forEach(room => {if (room !== socket.id) {socket.leave(room);}});`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's possible. You can leave rooms without disconnecting the socket. The socket disconnects only when you make a call to socket.disconnect().

To do this you'll have to maintain a list of rooms each client joins and leaves. To leave all rooms iterate through this list and make a call to socket.leave(roomname);

Comment: Thats really great.. Is there any possibility of getting exception when i try to leave a room which the socket has not joined earlier?

Comment: Version 0.8.7, that I'm referring, only considers the case where the the socket is leaving an existing room. Nothing is done if the room does not exist, not even an exception.

Comment: You don't need to maintain a list of rooms, socket.io does that for you. Simply iterate through the keys of `io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]` and `socket.leave` those.

Comment: For individual sockets its `socket.rooms`.

Comment: @Druska `io.sockets.adapter.sids[socket.id]` is the updated one to find rooms.
Below code to leave all rooms of socket.
`var rooms = io.sockets.adapter.sids[socket.id];
for(var room in rooms) {
      socket.leave(room);
    }`

Comment: @FahimBabarPatel this didn't work as of December 2017. io.socket.adapter does not exist. Also the / at the start of room name causes issues. This is the version that works for me, called within a individual socket context: ``for(var room in this.manager.roomClients[this.id]) {if (room == '') continue;this.leave(room.slice(1));}`` this version also makes certain not to leave the default room for self, which would break socket.emit(... I assume

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/1decae341c80c0417b32d3124ca30c005240b48a/lib/socket.js#L287

Comment: @v.tsurka - i cannot see `leaveAll()` in server api docs: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-leave-room-callback Do you know if it is documented somewhere? Maybe it exists but is undocumented, as `leaveAll()` is also mentioned here with a link to relevant line in source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53128858.  It seems to be working for me, verified by calling `socket.rooms` afterwards and getting an empty value.

Comment: if any one still interested :
io.adapter.allRooms((err, rooms) => {
          if(err) {
            return;
          }
          if(Array.isArray(rooms) && rooms.length) {
            rooms.map((room) => {
                socket.leave(room)
            })
          }
        });