# socket.io: only one room to a socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I would like to guarantee that a user is only in one room at a time, but I am having trouble implimenting this.  I have boiled the issue down to not being able to get a list of all the rooms a socket is currently in.

My current strategy is to do something like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A user just connected with id ' + socket.id);
    socket.on("change room", function(data) {
        // this SHOULD return a list of all rooms this user is in
        var socketsRooms = socket.rooms;
        console.log(socket.rooms) //{ '/#3tE4Up5PRbTfsU0JAAAD': '/#3tE4Up5PRbTfsU0JAAAD' }
        console.log(typeof socket.rooms) // object
        // Loop through the rooms and leave them
        for (var room in socketsRooms) {
            console.log('LEAVING ROOM: ', room);
            socket.leave(room);
        }

        // Join the new room
        socket.join(data.newroom);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user ' + socket.id + ' disconnected');
    });
})
```

Is there an issue in the docs with socket.rooms?  It says it should return an array of rooms that a socket is connected to, but I get back data as an id object. `EX: { '/#3tE4Up5PRbTfsU0JAAAD': '/#3tE4Up5PRbTfsU0JAAAD' }`

...  In my case I would expect something like `['issues']`

On the Socket.io [github page](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/) the socket.rooms description stated:

> A hash of strings identifying the rooms this socket is in, indexed by
>   room name.

BEFORE MARKING AS A DUPLICATE:

I have already checked out the folowing questions:

1. [How to leave all rooms that the socket is connected to at one go in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895925/how-to-leave-all-rooms-that-the-socket-is-connected-to-at-one-go-in-node-js?lq=1)
2. [socket.io: assure socket joins only one room at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114210/socket-io-assure-socket-joins-only-one-room-at-a-time)

The answer to the first question seems the most hacked together solution the I am pretty sure it will work because it assumes the solution as maintaining our own list, but I would prefer a working solution using socket.io over that method.

I am using the latest verion of socket.io v1.4.5 with angular2 beta on the client (if that helps out at all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In socket.io, each socket is also connected to its own room. This room has the same name of `socket.id`. So when leaving the rooms, make sure you don't leave its own room.

```
for(room in socket.rooms){
    if(socket.id !== room) socket.leave(room);
}
socket.join(data.newroom, function(){
  console.log('rooms', socket.rooms); // here you'll see two rooms: one with socket.id and another with data.newroom
});
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `let room of socket.rooms`, since `socket.rooms` is a Set in v2.