# How to unsubscribe a socket from a room when socket disconnected from the server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

If socket is disconnected from the server, Will all the subscription of that socket will be removed from the chat-room by default(by sails) or we have to remove it manually(by code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base of [socket.io source code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/54ff591b07ad17915ffd9f325448e72c9a76e828/lib/socket.js#L432) `this.leaveAll()` will run before fire disconnect event. So no need to leave from rooms manually

```
Socket.prototype.onclose = function(reason){
  if (!this.connected) return this;
  debug('closing socket - reason %s', reason);
  this.emit('disconnecting', reason);
  this.leaveAll();                    //  leave from all rooms
  this.nsp.remove(this);
  this.client.remove(this);
  this.connected = false;
  this.disconnected = true;
  delete this.nsp.connected[this.id];
  this.emit('disconnect', reason);   // disconnect event fire here
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Milad. Yes, all the connected socket are removed from the room on client disconnect. I also verified with Object.keys(sails.io.sockets.connected) - which will return only connected sockets to the server.